# Transparent JPanel with customises close button

Tags: java, swing, transparency, transparent

we already know how to make transparent JPanel just like what we see here on the picture that I took from utube and shown below but how they put this customized close button that half of it is out of the JPanel and the other half is in the air? is there any easy way to do it?

[image]
   this is what I ment

[well please look on that picture that will describe you my question][ please check this on]

Comment: *"is there any easy way to do it ?"*  Hire someone that knows what their doing (is easy).

Comment: ^ And knows how to do it right (not like setting the background of a panel with a alpha based color)

Comment: well Andrew Thompson I think I know u, u r the one who is always have a time to answer stupid short things without writing anything smart  that will answer the ppl need. next time please don't answer to my question if u dont have a smart answer !!! HO and mad programmer... please look on the second picture that I sent , u will c that I am not so stupid as u think I am !

Answer (score 0):

You make a transparent frame, with a translucent panel, you ensure that the panel is offset within the frame using layout properties (something like `GridBagLayout` would be able to achieve it) and add the button to the top right corner, again, with some trickery, you can `GridBagLayout` to do it

As a rough [example](Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses)

You might like to take a look at [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: well I allready did that 
 ` code         add(button, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                                               GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END,
                                               GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL,
                                               new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    mT.dataPanel.hideMessageLayer();
     mT.layerUI.stop();
                }
            });` but its not the same

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, and update your question. This will result in less confusion and better responses